# Firebase not displaying rich push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, rich-media

I am using firebase notification in my application. I want to send rich notification but firebase console don't have UI for same. So I am trying to send the payload using postman.

I have created Notification Service Extension for handling content but it never gets called.

Deployment target in xCode is **iOS 10.0** and iPad has **iOS 11**

Json payload(Not Working):

```
  {
    "to":"/topics/dev_news",
   "mutable_content": true,
   "data":
   {
        "attachment-url":"my image url",
        "media_type":"image"

   }

}
```

**FYI:
I am able to receive push if I add "notification" key-value in payload.**

Json payload(Working but without media):

```
{
    "to":"/topics/dev_news",
   "mutable_content": true,
   "data":
   {
        "attachment-url":"my image url",
        "media_type":"image"

   },
   "notification" : {
    "title" : "demo push",
    "body" : "this is push body"
   }

}
```

Any idea about this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question, I was searching for `attachment-url` in `data` dictionary (which I was passing in the payload) in service extension class. But `attachment-url` comes directly in the `content.userInfo` (It is not wrapped inside the `data` dictionary) in extension class.

Wondering how I can make such a silly mistake..!! :D

Comment: I'm having the same kind of problem, image won't display and as I saw you answer I saw that I was doing the same, Getting the value from `content.userInfo`still doesn't show images. Could you please check my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568098/incoming-rich-push-notifications-wont-show-the-image-swift-4? I'd really appreciate it. Many thanks.